# Exclude web part from flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web

After a new update I noticed that when I use `Flutter create myproject` I includes web folder as well either I want it or not. So my question is that

> Is there anyway to exclude web portion during `FLutter create`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute this command before creating the project:

```
$ flutter config --no-enable-web
```